# Cannot get ip address on raspberry pi

Tags: ip, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to ssh to my raspberry pi so I wanted to get the ip address as mentioned in the following link using

```
 ifconfig
```

http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-6-using-ssh/using-ssh-on-a-mac-or-linux

```
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:63:40:b8
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:27224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:733 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
  RX bytes:2801074 (2.6 MiB)  TX bytes:107019 (104.5 KiB)

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
  RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
  RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I did not get the list that starts with `wlan0`

I even tried typing `sudo ifconfig wlan0` but I got the following error

```
wlan0 error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

I'm connected through a wired cable and yes I'm connected to the internet since I can browse websites and for the moment I do not wanna set up any wireless connection I just want to be able to get my ip so I can login to the pi using the ip address

is there anyway I can get my raspberry pi's ip address

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm logged in physically to the pi trying to get the ip address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know exactly what was the problem but when I was using the ip I was getting from ifconfig I was not able to ssh to my pi when I typed

```
ip route
```

I got another ip so I used that and tried to shh to my pi and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo ifconfig -a
```

if you want to use ifconfig, but as it is deprecated you should use

```
sudo hostname --ip-address
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be connected to the network. Although just to double check, connect to your router (usually 192.168.0.1 - if not ipconfig on your machine, then go to your default gateway), login, go to devices and look for the mac address from your pi (b8:27:eb:63:40:b8) You can check the Local IP address from there... If it is connected to the network properly though

Comment: I'm logged in to the pi (not remotely) and I tried opening some websites to make sure Im connected

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a wlan-card connected to the device? Is it via USB? Did it install correctly?

Do you have a working network connection at all on the device? Try pinging something, for example

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

and see if you get a response. If not, you are not connected to internet, and need to either install a wireless card via USB or connect a network cable.

Comment: I'm connected through a wired cable and yes I'm connected to the internet since I can browse websites and for the moment I do not wanna set up any wireless connection I just want to be able to get my ip so I can login to the pi using the ip address

Answer (score 0):

For `ifconfig` to work, you have to be connected to the device. Plugging in ethernet cables does not ensure that your computer has recognized the connection. Here is what you can try-

- Go to Network Settings -> Edit Connections
- Add a new connection
- In IPv4 settings, change Method to "Shared with other computers"

If everything goes well, you will see connected notification. Try doing `ifconfig` again.

Sometimes, the IP address shown in `ifconfig` might not work. In that case, just use `nmap` to search the subnet (the last digit of IP address), and try to login on other IPs.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :
hostname -I

This should show u the IP address of ur RPi if it is set.
If it isn't set, type
sudo nano cmdline.txt

And in this file append the following in the end
IP=192.168.0.4

This should set the IP and by typing the command, you should be able to see it..